# How to call some Service methods from a ListView Adapter?

Tags: android, service, adapter

I have a `ListView` with a list of downloads. Each item has a `Button` to start/pause/stop a download.

All download-related processes are performed into a `Service`.

How can I call my download `Service` methods (download/pause/...) from the `ListView` `Adapter`?

The `Fragment` in which I set the adapter is bound to the service, so it has the service instance.

Shall I just pass the `Service` instance to the `Adapter`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you service needs to be bound to the activity. In this way you can communicate in a client-server way. There are multiple ways to handle this:

- If your service will be bound to only one process at a time, you can use a simple bound service and communicate through an IBinder interface
- If your service may be called asynchronously by different processes or threads you should use a bound service that implements a Messenger pattern.

In your case I think you should use the first one. Read this to understand how to accomplish your task:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html